# Replace column values with column name using dplyr's transmute_all

Tags: r, dplyr

Data set contains many columns containing values which are either NA or 1, kind of like this:

```
> data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), b=c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 NA     1.00
2  1.00 NA   
3 NA     1.00
4  1.00  1.00
5  1.00 NA
```

Desired output: replace all the 1 values with the name of the column as a string,

```
> data_frame(a = c(NA, 'a', NA, 'a', 'a'), b=c('b', NA, 'b', 'b', NA))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 <NA>  b    
2 a     <NA> 
3 <NA>  b    
4 a     b    
5 a     <NA>
```

here's my attempt using an anonymous function in transmute_all:

```
> data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), b=c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA)) %>%
+     transmute_all(
+         funs(function(x){if (x == 1) deparse(substitute(x)) else NA})
+     )
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `a` is of unsupported type function
```

EDIT: Attempt # 2:

```
> data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), b=c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA)) %>%
+     transmute_all(
+         funs(
+             ((function(x){if (!is.na(x)) deparse(substitute(x)) else NA})(.))
+             )
+     )
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  a     b    
  <lgl> <chr>
1 NA    b    
2 NA    b    
3 NA    b    
4 NA    b    
5 NA    b    
Warning messages:
1: In if (!is.na(x)) deparse(substitute(x)) else NA :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!is.na(x)) deparse(substitute(x)) else NA :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick with a `dplyr` solution you almost already had it

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), b = c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA))

df %>% 
    transmute_all(funs(ifelse(. == 1, deparse(substitute(.)), NA)))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>     a     b    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  b    
#> 2 a     <NA> 
#> 3 <NA>  b    
#> 4 a     b    
#> 5 a     <NA>
```

Comment: Without `funs()` that is deprecated, now do: `transmute_all(function(x) ifelse(x == 1, deparse(substitute(x)), NA))`. This is superseded too, and now should be done using `across()`, but that won't help you, as it returns "col" for all values, except if you construct it with `cur_column()`. Don't mind `across()`, it's very inconvenient IMHO...

Answer (score 8):

One option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(df1, names(df1), ~  replace(.x, .x==1, .y))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  a     b    
# <chr> <chr>
#1 NA    b    
#2 a     NA   
#3 NA    b    
#4 a     b    
#5 a     NA
```

Or as @Moody_Mudskipper commented

```
imap_dfr(df1, ~replace(.x, .x==1, .y))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
df1[] <- names(df1)[col(df1) *(df1 == 1)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), b=c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA))
```

Comment: great answer. gave the check to the other answer because it uses pure dplyr, as requested in the question.  Thanks.

Comment: or `imap_dfr(df1, ~replace(.x, .x==1, .y))` to be slightly more compact

Answer (score 3):

Base `R` should be fine as well:

```
nn <- names(df)
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[i] <- ifelse(df[i] == 1, nn[i], df[i])
}
```

This yields

```
     a    b
1 <NA>    b
2    a <NA>
3 <NA>    b
4    a    b
5    a <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `deparse(substitute(.))` will return a length 1 string, you can just subset directly with `.`, as subsetting with `NA` returns `NA`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), 
                 b = c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA))

df %>% mutate_all(funs(deparse(substitute(.))[.]))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   a     b    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  b    
#> 2 a     <NA> 
#> 3 <NA>  b    
#> 4 a     b    
#> 5 a     <NA>
```

An approach that does not involve parsing names is to reshape to long form so the variable names are a variable that can be operated on as usual. Here, coercing to a logical vector makes subsetting behave the same as above. Adding an index column is necessary if you want to maintain row order in reshaping back to wide form.

```r
df %>% 
    rowid_to_column('i') %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -i) %>% 
    mutate(value = variable[as.logical(value)]) %>% 
    spread(variable, value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>       i a     b    
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 <NA>  b    
#> 2     2 a     <NA> 
#> 3     3 <NA>  b    
#> 4     4 a     b    
#> 5     5 a     <NA>
```

Comment: `funs` is soft-deprecated. How can we replace it in this context?

Comment: A very concise way to keep the same logic would be with `purrr::imodify`: `df %>% imodify(~.y[.x])`

Comment: or instead of `funs` you'd need to use a full anonymous funciton: `df %>% mutate_all(function(x) deparse(substitute(x))[x])`. purrr-style `~` quoted lambda notation doesn't seem to work, presumably because of the way it's parsed.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. You could update your answer with this.